# how do i set the text for a custom dialog i created from another activity/class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, dialog

I created this CustomDialog class for my Kotlin app:

```
class CustomDialog(private val context: Context) {
    private lateinit var dialog: Dialog

    lateinit var title: TextView
    lateinit var message: TextView

    fun show() {
        dialog = Dialog(context)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom)
        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(null)
        dialog.setCancelable(true)

        title = dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_title)
        message = dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_message)

        dialog.create()
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

it's supposed to be a dummy for different types of dialogs because I'd prefer not to create a new one every time with a different xml for each one. The problem is that when I call the .setText method to set the string I want to show, I either get an UnitializedPropertyException when I use lateinit or a NullPointer when I initialize it as null and I can't wrap my head around how to solve this.

the method to set the text is simply an onclicklistener that tries to .setText() on title and message and a .show() right after.

I come from a Java background and adjusting to Kotlin is giving me a bit of problems like this one. Hope someone can point me in the right direction, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use `DialogFragment`? If you use DialogFragment, then, you can use ViewModel and try using dataBinding. here's the [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding?authuser=1)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this documentation? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/dialogs#kotlin

For custom builds there is DialogFragment class.

You can achieve this using the following code:

```
CustomDialog(
    Configuration.build {
        customTitle = "Custom Title"
        customMessage = "Custom Message"
        customCancelable = false
    }
).show(supportFragmentManager, CustomDialog.TAG)
```

And here is the CustomDialog class with a builder:

```
import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment

class CustomDialog(private val configuration: Configuration) : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let { it ->
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)

            configuration.customTitle?.let{ title ->
                builder.setTitle(title)
            }

            configuration.customMessage?.let{ message ->
                builder.setMessage(message)
            }

            builder.setCancelable(configuration.customCancelable)

            // TODO: ...

            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "CustomDialog"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way to do it.

Just create view and set to a view and assign view to Dialog.

Here is code example in kotlin

```
class CustomDialog(private val context: Context , title : String, content: String) {
    var builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        var view = View.inflate(changePasswordActivity,R.layout.progress,null)
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvProgress).setText(title).setMessage(content)
        builder.setView(view)
            .setCancelable(false)

        val alertDialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
        alertDialog.show()
}
```